# proving isomorphism of two $k$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field. I would like to prove that $k[x,y]/(x^3-y^2) \cong k[t^2,t^3]$. Of course, intuitively, i can readily see that this must be the case.
More formally, i define a homomorphism $\phi:k[x,y]/(x^3-y^2) \rightarrow k[t^2,t^3]$, by sending the class of $x$ to $t^2$ and the class of $y$ to $t^3$. Then $\phi$ is well defined and surjective. Injectivity seems to be somewhat complicated. I thought of giving a grading to the ring $k[x,y]$ by assigning the grade $2a_1+3a_2$ to the monomial $x^{a_1}y^{a_2}$. Then it is enough to prove that if two monomials $x^{a_1}y^{a_2}, x^{a_1'}y^{a_2'}$ have the same grade, then their difference is in the ideal $(x^3-y^2)$. But showing this seems to be a little bit messy (or not?) Any elegant ideas for finishing the proof or for an alternative proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f$ be a polynomial sent to zero by your homomorphism. Divide it by $y^2-x^3$ (long division as a polynomial in $y$. We can do it because its leading coefficient is $1$). We get a remainder of degree $<2$ in $y$, i.e. $a(x)y+b(x)$ such that it is mapped to zero by $x=t^2$, $y=t^3$. But $a(t^2)t^3$ has all terms of odd degree, while $b(t^2)$ has even degrees. Therefore $a(x)=b(x)=0$. So, the polynomial $f$ is divisible by $y^2-x^3$.

This **shows** that the kernel of the map $k[x,y]\rightarrow k[t^2,t^3]$ **is** the ideal $(x^3-y^2)$.

Comment: This establishes that the kernel is *contained* in $(x^3-y^2)$, but then yeah afterwards it's easy to see that $x^3-y^2$ is in the kernel, proving the reverse containment.